# cells full of NaN with the use of stack() in python to convert headers to rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas, stack

I have this datasets, two columns are one header (age, sex) and another two columns are two headers (wk1 and wk2):

```
                             wk1             wk2    
ID         age    sex   Note1   Note2   Note1   Note2
1123        22     M    10       22      233       2
1198        34     M    9        4       44       23
101         28     F    3        6       3        43
```

when I use `pd.read_excel('file',header=[0,1], index_col=0).stack(0).reset_index()`
I got this resut:

```
ID  level_0   level_1               Note 1  Note 2  age     sex
0   1123      Unnamed: 1_level_0    NaN     NaN     22.0    NaN
1   1123      Unnamed: 2_level_0    NaN     NaN     NaN      M
2   1123        wk1                 10.0    22.0    NaN     NaN 
3   1123        wk2                 233.0   2.0     NaN     NaN
4   1198      Unnamed: 1_level_0    NaN     NaN     34.0    NaN
5   1198      Unnamed: 2_level_0    NaN     NaN     NaN      M
6   1198       wk1                  9.0     4.0     NaN     NaN
...
```

What I want to get as results is :

```
ID      age    sexe   Wk      Note 1     Note 2
1123     22     M     wk1       10         22
1198     34     M     wk1        9          4
101      28     F     wk1        3          6
1123     22     M     wk2      233          2
1198     34     M     wk2       44         23
101      28     F     wk2        3         43
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do some re-shaping to your data with `replace` `ffill/bfill`

and `pd.crosstab`

Honestly, it's easier to fix this sort of data at source if you can, I've dealt with similar stuff from a SAP system which would always come out pivoted with lots of merged cells and random rows (written by many years of SAP analysts)

```
df = pd.read_excel(file,
             header=[0,1],
              index_col=[0]).stack([0,1])\
              .reset_index().rename(columns={'ID' : 'header',
                                             'level_0' : 'ID',
                                             'level_1' : 'weeks',
                                              0 : 'value'})
              

df['weeks'] = df['weeks'].replace('Unnamed.*',np.nan,regex=True).bfill().ffill()

df1 = pd.crosstab(
    [df["ID"], df["weeks"]], df["header"], values=df["value"], aggfunc=lambda x: x
).reset_index()
```

---

```
print(df1.groupby('ID').ffill())

  weeks Note1 Note2 age sex
0   wk1     3     6  28   F
1   wk2     3    43  28   F
2   wk1    10    22  22   M
3   wk2   233     2  22   M
4   wk1     9     4  34   M
5   wk2    44    23  34   M
```